# React.JS State Update with Socket.io session data

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to update the state of a react app with data from a websocket and it all works but the issue is this:

In the view where I monitor the users currently logged in, the state is only reflecting the second to last update and not the last. If I refresh the page the data (I'm passing a current_url) gets updated but if I navigate to the page from another page, the previous url is shown instead of the current. I'm assuming that the state array is being updated only after the component renders and showing an old state.

I've tried using the `setState` callback to `forceUpdate()` but this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

```
class UsersLoggedIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            usersLoggedIn: []
        }
    }
    getUsersLogged() {
        const socketIo = SocketIO();
        if (typeof socketIo === 'object') {
            socketIo.emit('getUsersLogged', (data) => {
                const usersLoggedIn = [];

                // groups the data from the socket by session id.
                for (let id in data) {
                    let temp = [];
                    for (let socketId in data[id]) {
                        temp.push(data[id][socketId]);
                    }
                    usersLoggedIn.push({
                        ...temp[0],
                        children: temp
                    });
                }
                this.setState({usersLoggedIn}, () => {
                    this.forceUpdate();
                });
            });
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        // we need to pass data to the socket here.
        const socketIo = SocketIO();
        if (typeof socketIo === 'object') {
            socketIo.on('loadUserLogged', (data) => {
                this.getUsersLogged();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, try: `this.setState({ usersLoggedIn: [...usersLoggedIn]})`

Comment: Since componentDidMount is called post the initial render, its expected that the state updated will happen after the initial render

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes I know that there is one initial render, however once the state updates the component should re-render to reflect the new state correct? At least is what normally happens, the issue here seems to be that the function completes, and renders before the new data is passed to React State.